# context.moveTo() x and y parameters are not decrementing using requestAnimationFrame

Tags: javascript, canvas, trigonometry

I have two lines at a 90 degree angle and I want to make the angle get smaller and larger between 90 and 0 by rotating the vertical line. I'm trying to do this my changing the `moveTo` parameters I could increase the value but not decrease them. also could you help me make sure that the line that moves is the same length as the horizontal line during the animation. now it looks like it gets smaller then gets larger as it completes.

```js
window.onload = function(){
 var canvas =document.getElementById("canvas");
 var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
 var length = 50;
 var x = 50;
 var y= 50;
 var forward = true;

 
 (function animate(){
  if(x  <= 201 && y <= 201){
   x++
   y++
   
  }
  if(x  > 195){
   forward = false;
  }
  // console.log(x, y)
   if(forward == false){
    // alert("yo")
   x = x - 1
   y = y -1
  }
  console.log(x)
  console.log(forward)
  context.clearRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(x,y)
  context.lineTo(50,200);
  context.stroke();
  context.closePath();
  window.requestAnimationFrame(animate)
  

  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(50, 200);
  context.lineTo(200, 200)
  context.stroke();
  context.closePath();

 }())
   }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

EDIT:::

```js
window.onload = function(){
 var canvas =document.getElementById("canvas");
 var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
 var length = 50;
 var x = 50;
 var y= 50;
 var dlt  = 1
 var forward = true;
 var i = 0;

 
 (function animate(){
  if(x >= 50 && x < 200 ){
   i++

   x += dlt
   y += dlt
   console.log(i)
   $(".display").html(i)
   if(i >= 150){
    X = 200;
    Y = 200;
    x -= dlt
    y -= dlt
   }
   
  }

  console.log("x", x)
  console.log(forward)
  context.clearRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(x,y)
  context.lineTo(50,200);
  context.stroke();
  context.closePath();
  window.requestAnimationFrame(animate)
  

  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(50, 200);
  context.lineTo(200, 200)
  context.stroke();
  context.closePath();

 }())

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use transformations instead of trigonometry to draw your vertically collapsing line:

Here is annotated code and a Demo:

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

var nextTime=0;
var delay=100;
var angle=-Math.PI/2;
var cx=150;
var cy=150;
var radius=50;

requestAnimationFrame(animate);

function animate(time){

  // wait until the desired time elapses
  if(time<nextTime){requestAnimationFrame(animate); return;}
  nextTime+=delay;

  // draw the horizontal line
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(cx,cy);
  ctx.lineTo(cx+radius,cy);
  ctx.stroke();

  // use transformations to draw the vertical line
  // at the desired angle
  ctx.translate(cx,cy);
  ctx.rotate(angle);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(0,0);
  ctx.lineTo(radius,0);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);

  // if the vertical line isn't horizontal, 
  // request another animation frame
  if(angle<0){ requestAnimationFrame(animate); }

  // adjust the angle
  angle+=Math.PI/90;
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

If you want to use Trig then you can calculate the line endpoint like this:

```
var lineX1 = lineX0 + radius*Math.cos(angle);
var lineY1 = lineY1 + radius*Math.sin(angle);
```

**[Addition: add trigonometry to questioner's code]**

Here is your code refactored to use trigonometry to reposition the vertical line.

```js
var canvas =document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var length = 50;
var x = 50;
var y= 50;
var dlt  = 1
var forward = true;
var i = 0;

var angle=-Math.PI/2;
var direction=1;

(function animate(){

  /*
  if(x >= 50 && x < 200 ){
   i++

   x += dlt
   y += dlt
   console.log(i)
   $(".display").html(i)
   if(i >= 150){
    X = 200;
    Y = 200;
    x -= dlt
    y -= dlt
   }

  }
*/

  var moveX=50+(200-50)*Math.cos(angle);
  var moveY=200+(200-50)*Math.sin(angle);

  // change the angle
  angle+=(Math.PI/120*direction);

  // if the angle is beyond vertical or horizontal then
  // swing it the other way
  if(angle<-Math.PI/2 || angle>0){ direction*=-1;}

  context.clearRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(moveX,moveY)
  context.lineTo(50,200);
  context.stroke();
  //  context.closePath();

  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(50, 200);
  context.lineTo(200, 200)
  context.stroke();
  //  context.closePath();

  window.requestAnimationFrame(animate)

}())
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I admire your work but I really want to know what I did wrong. I tried to do it again by changing the x and y parameters of the moveTo() and I put it in the edit of the question I really want to know why x is not decreasing  and how could I get it to decrease by 1 when x is at 200  so it could start rotating up. as for your answer I'm not sure how setTransform() works here. I tried reading the Mozilla docs.

Comment: @jackblank. Cool. I've added to my answer to show how to modify your code to use trigonometry to calculate the `moveTo` coordinates. :-)

Comment: This is the effect I wanted and I'm going to accept  this answer soon. I see how your using trig to get the moveTo() part to go across an invisible  circle so the vertical line appears to have the same size as the horizontal. This is good. I'm just concerned about **my**  logic. I couldn't get the x and y values to decrease in my code. right now I'm just wondering about how my logic didn't work. not about using the x value just how do I get it to decrease when x is at 200. I would of thought x would decrease when the counter `i` hit 150 and that is troubling me.

Comment: When the line reaches horizontal you can make `dlt` negative to start the line moving back towards vertical. And when it reaches vertical you can make it positive again to move the line towards horizontal.

Answer (score 1):

**Sin and Cos**

All graphics programmers should know these two trigonometric functions thoroughly.

**MarkE** has given a good answer but I will point out the simple trig method that you can use to find a point that is a desired distance and angle.

Lets say the line you want has a length,

```
var length = 100;
```

its starts at,

```
var posX = 200;
var posY = 200;
```

the unknown end location will be,

```
var endX;
var endY;
```

and the angle you want is

```
var angle = 0; // in radians
```

**Radians V Degrees**
In javascript all Math functions that require angles use angle as radians.
The above `angle` is in radians, with `angle = 0` pointing from left to right across the screen, `angle = Math.PI/2` (90deg) from top down the screen, `angle = Math.PI` (180deg) from right to left across the screen and `angle = Math.PI * (3/2)` (270deg) from bottom to top up the screen.

If you like to work in degrees then you can convert to radians by multiplying degrees by `Math.PI/180.`

Function to convert degrees to radians

```
function degree2Radians(deg){
    return deg * (Math.PI/180);
}
```

Back to getting the line at an angle. We will use the trig functions `Math.cos` and `Math.sin` see Wiki [trigonometric functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions) for details.

So the calculation in steps

```
var x,y; // temp working variables
x = Math.cos(angle);  // get the amount of x in the line for angle
y = Math.sin(angle);  // get the amount of y in the line for angle 
// cos and sin will return values -1 to 1 inclusive.

// now scale the values to the length of the line
x *= length;
y *= length;

// now you have the offset from the start of the line
// to get the end point add the start
endX = x + posX;
endY = y + posY;
```

Now you can draw the line at the angle you wanted.

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(posX,posY);
ctx.lineTo(endX,endY);
ctx.stroke();
```

Of course that was a long way. It all can be done in two steps.

```
endX = Math.cos(angle) * length + posX;
endY = Math.sin(angle) * length + posY;
```

or if you like a function that works in degrees

```
// add to the current path a line from 
// startX,startY of 
// length pixels long
// at the angle angleDeg in degrees. Negative anticlockwise positive clockwise
function lineAtAngle(ctx, startX, startY, angleDeg, length){
    var angle = angleDeg * (Math.PI / 180);
    ctx.moveTo(startX, startY);
    ctx.lineTo(
        Math.cos(angle) * length + startX,
        Math.sin(angle) * length + startY
    )
}
```

And to use it

```
ctx.beginPath(); // begin the line
lineAtAngle(ctx,200,200,-45,100); // draw a line at -45deg 
                                  // (from bottom left to top right)
                                  // 100 pixels long.
ctx.stroke();  // draw the line
```

Thats how to use sin and cos to draw a line at an angle and length.

Comment: Nice explanation. And agreed...a bit of "triangle geometry" (=trigonometry) is a very useful tool when drawing. :-)

Comment: @Blindman67 Thanks for your explanation. Just want to confirm something. When you use `x *= length; `length  is the radius of unit circle? and `length`  makes the length of the line? also that line is called the  **terminal side**?

Comment: Before multiplying by the `length`, `x` and `y` (from `x = cos(a)` & `y = sin(a)`) represents the radius of the unit circle which is of course 1. `x,y` can be said to be a unit vector (or normalised vector) pointing in the direction of `angle`. Multiplying by `length` scales the unit vector (x,y) to the required length. Yes it is the **terminal side**. On the canvas the terminal side starts pointing to the right (@ `angle = 0`) and rotates clockwise as the angle increases.